# To solve this numerically :

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, numerical-methods, computational-mathematics

$$0.5 = 1 −{0.955}^n − {0.005}^n{0.995}^{n −1}n − {0.005}^2{0.995}^{n −2}\left(\frac{n(n−1)}{2}\right)$$

I'm using MatLab but should I use a for-loop? Can anyone work me through the steps?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Matlab and Octave `fsolve` is a nice function for finding roots to functions.

First you need a "function handle" for your function, you can do this defining it as a *lambda* expression and assigning it a name, say `f`:

```
f = @(n)1-(0.955^n) - (0.005^n)*(0.995^(n-1))*n - (0.005^2)*(0.995^(n-2))*n*((n−1)/2) - 0.5;
```

now typing

```
n_solved = fsolve(f, n_guess);
```

will probably find the numerical solution closest to your guess.

Comment: I got this:
fh = @(n) 1-(0.955.^n)-(0.005.^n)*(0.995.^(n-1))*n-(0.005.^2)*(0.995.^(n-2))*n((n-1)/2)- 0.5;
s = functions(fh) 
n_solved = fsolve(fh, n_guess);

Comment: It's important to have * or .* symbol between each expression to make multiplication so you will need ...*n*(n-1)/2 at the end. If you just have parentheses to the right of a symbol the parser will think you are trying to index an array.

Comment: As the function is univariate, `fzero` would probably be a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Newton's Method to solve the equation numerically:

Set $f(n) = 1−0.955^n −0.005^n\cdot0.995^{n −1}\cdot n− 0.005^2\cdot0.995^{n −2}\cdot \frac{n(n−1)}{2} -0.5$

Then $n$ is a solution of your equation exactly when $n$ is a root of $f$,that is $f(n) = 0$.

Newton's method goes like this:

$x_{m+1} = x_m - \frac{f(x_m)}{f'(x_m)}$

where $f'(n)$ is the derivative of $f$ with respect to $n$.
Choose some starting value $x_0$ to get started with the iteration.

Edited:

As Michael said, you could plot the function and get an approximate value $x_0$ for $n$, which you could use as the starting value of the Newton iteration if the value of $x_0$ is not accurate enough for your needs.

Comment: its n(n-1)/2 ! not n(n-1/2).
Sorry

Comment: This is a good approach as long as the function is differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

I would plot the function:

```
n=0.001:0.001:20;  
plot(n,1-(0.995.^n) - (0.005.^n).*(0.995.^(n-1)).*n - (0.005^2)*(0.995.^(n-2)).*(n.*(n-1))/2)
```

Then see where the graph cuts `0.5`.

Comment: yeah 0.995 and its raised to n-1 and n-2 and its (n-1)/2